# Validation of Unique Entity

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an account entity which contains a foreign key constraint for a user entity and customer entity.

I'm trying to validate the customer id is numeric and not null.  Plus the unique constraint of user_id and customer_id.

My problem the Class Constraint UniqueEntity gets fired regardless of the outcome of the customer_id type: numeric validation result.  Which throws a 500 because the customer_id column is an integer.

What I need to do is, validate the customer_id is a valid id (numeric and not null) before checking the unique constraint.  Or is there any other way to avoid symfony/doctrine going to the db to test an invalid id?

My validation config,

```
MY\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Account:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [ user_id, customer_id ]
            message: Customer Id already exists for User
    properties:
        customer_id:
            - Type:
                type: numeric
                message: Customer Id should be an integer.
            - NotBlank:
                message: Customer cannot be blank.
```

Comment: I should add this is an api call, I don't serve the form from a symfony template.  Sending a string like "test" as customer id throws these sql errors.  I don't see the point of the extra db call if its not needed.  Would be nice if you could define a tree of dependant validations.

Comment: I do believe that might be possible with group sequences. Maybe this helps you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Group Sequences](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence) should solve your problem here. Something like that should work:

```
MY\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Account:
    group_sequence:
        - Basic
        - Account
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [ user_id, customer_id ]
            message: Customer Id already exists for User
    properties:
        customer_id:
            - Type:
                type: numeric
                message: Customer Id should be an integer.
                groups: [Basic]
            - NotBlank:
                message: Customer cannot be blank.
                groups: [Basic]
```

With group sequences you can define the order of your validations. `Basic` checks all constraints with the group `Basic` and `Account` cheks the other constraints for this entity.

Comment: If the Basic group fails the Account group wouldn't run?